# Rendering two wire-frames in 3DS Max?

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max

Is there a way to render an object together with double wire-frames in 3DS Max?

- Wire-frame 1 - The original geometry of the model - which on the render will curve by following the shape of the model
- Wire-frame 2 - The geometry that is created by the turbo-smooth modifier that will remain straight.

It is quite useful for showing the topology together with the deformation of the geometry.

Something like this - 
[image]

Is something like that possible to make in 3DS Max?

Update -

Note - the wire-frame to be equal, relative to the object or relative to the screen. By that I mean - the edges to be with equal thickness.

Is something like that possible to do?

Comment: I know that there is a way to do it with a texture, but the thing is that I want the edges to be equil. That is, every edge to be the same thickness relative to do object or relative to the screen. Is something like possible to make?

Comment: It might be helpful to review [the types of questions](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) which should and should not be asked. Specifically what to [avoid asking](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). **Simple "how to" question" are customarily not desirable.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could render multiple wireframe passes and compose them together - with a bit of work, this could be automated.

Comment: Sure, if you duplicate the object, you can render both wireframes at once, but this has its own issues. It's simpler to compose two passes.

Comment: At first I thought "composite" stands for pixel work (after the render process), but now I know it is a material.

How is that done?

Comment: Check out this tutorial: http://blog.digitaltutors.com/two-easy-methods-rendering-wireframes-3ds-max/

Comment: Compositing is pixels work in Blender and that was my confusion. Thanks for the tutorial.